# Not able to open spyder in conda environment

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, spyder

I try to launch spyder in conda environment after installing all this packages:

```
conda create -n env python=3.6 anaconda
conda activate env
conda install theano
conda install tensorflow
conda install keras
conda update --all
spyder
```

The first issue was this:

```
/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: /anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No such file or directory
```

So i run this command:

```
conda install -f python.app
```

But now i got this error:

```
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/pythonw: line 3: 38753 Illegal instruction: 4  /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

Can someone help me ? I'm on mac M1 and i saw on different forum that this error might be due for this

Comment: Where's Spyder installed? - there's no command to install Spyder in the environment. Also, I'd recommend getting familiar with [the Spyder documentation on using Conda environments as kernels](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder).

Comment: Interesting that your conda command is using the homebrew python - is that expected?  I thought anaconda came with it's own python, which would reside in `/opt` or `~/opt`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can just edit the file in the error message (`/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/pythonw`) and change the path to the correct location of your python executable, which should be:

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

or
~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

From here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9951